# Injective field homomorphism implies surjective?

Tags: field-theory

Suppose that $\sigma: F\to F$ is injective field homomorphism. Does it follow that $\sigma$ is surjective?

I know that is $F$ is finite field then it's true.

Is it true in general case?

Comment: Not in general. $F=\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\ldots)$ and map $x_i\longmapsto x_{i+1}$.

Comment: However, if $F$ is of finite degree over its prime field (as for example in the finite case), then the answer is "yes", because $\sigma$ will be a linear transformation of $F$ to itself as a vector space over the prime field, and being finite dimensional, injectivity implies surjectivity. More generally, if $F$ is of finite degree over $\{a\in F\mid \sigma(a)=a\}$, then the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 2):

Any field homomorphism is injective.

A simple counterexample is given by considering the field of rational functions $F(x)$ of the field $F$ over the indeterminate $x$, and the unique homomorphism $F(x)\to F(x)$ that is the identity on $F$ and maps $x$ to $x^2$.